# Form's Date Value not able to bring it over to VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a query, called "RosterQC" that filters results based on the text object "Text35" in the Form "Quality":

```
  SELECT Record No
  FROM TableX
  WHERE Date = [Forms]![Quality]![Text35]
```

Running the query itself is fine, but when I try to run it on VBA. It gives me an error 3061 - too few parameters expected 1. My VBA code as of below,

```
Sub Duplicate()
DoCmd.RunSQL "Delete * from old_table"
CurrentDb.Execute "Insert Into old_table Select RosterQC.* From RosterQC"
DoCmd.OpenReport "RosterQC_Report", View:=acViewPreview
End Sub
```

Appreciate if someone please give help me by providing me with some insights or solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the parameter to the query before running it but, in this case, it might be simpler to rewrite the task:

```vb
Sub Duplicate()

    Dim Sql As String

    Sql = "Delete * from old_table"
    CurrentDb.Execute Sql
    Sql = "Insert Into old_table Select [Record No] From TableX Where [Date] = #" & Format([Forms]![Quality]![Text35], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
    CurrentDb.Execute Sql

    DoCmd.OpenReport "RosterQC_Report", View:=acViewPreview
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass the parameter without writing "Select [Record No] From TableX Where..."? because my actual SQL is complicated.

Comment: When I add in WHERE  [Date] = #" & Format([Forms]![Quality]![Text35], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#", it gives the same parameter error message. If I remove anything beyond WHERE statement, it runs fine. but I need the WHERE Statement to filter the query result. Please help.

Comment: _Is there a way_ - yes, open the query as a QueryDef object, set the parameter, open a recordset using the QueryDef object, loop the recordset and append the records one by one to the old_table.

Comment: _it gives the same parameter error message_ - then the form isn't open.

Comment: I found a way to get around with it by create a message box. I know is silly. lol